# Issue while implementing JobListener interface Pentaho 9.3 BA server. The jobExecutionException parameter in the method jobWasExecuted is always null

Tags: java, pentaho, quartz-scheduler

I am currently using Pentaho BI Server version 9.3 and have set up several scheduled subscriptions that run automatically at specified times.

My goal is to retrieve the status of each subscription after it runs, whether it succeeds or fails.

To achieve this, I developed a Java plugin that implements the JobListener interface. The interface method jobWasExecuted receives two parameters: JobExecutionContext and JobExecutionException.

To determine the job's error status, I expect the JobExecutionException parameter to contain an error object if any issues occur during execution. However, regardless of whether the job succeeds or fails, the JobExecutionException parameter always remains null.

This behavior is inconsistent with my experience using Pentaho BI Server version 6.1, where the plugin was functioning correctly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.